# When does objectValueForTableColumn: get called?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am currently going through the 3rd Edition of the Mac OSX Cocoa book from the Big Nerd Ranch guys and I am editing my program to include table views. Here the code from the AppController.m file where I have to implement the required protocol methods from the TableView:

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];

    voiceArray = [NSSpeechSynthesizer availableVoices];
    speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
    [speechSynth setDelegate:self];
    return self;
}

-(int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv{
    NSLog(@"Getting number of rows in table view: %lu", [voiceArray count]);
    return [voiceArray count];
}

-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

    NSString *v = [voiceArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSSpeechSynthesizer attributesForVoice:v];
    NSLog(@"Voice Name %@", [dict objectForKey:NSVoiceName]);
    return [dict objectForKey:NSVoiceName];
}

-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    int row = [tableView selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"row selected %d", row);
    if(row == 1){
        return;
    }
    NSString *selectedVoice = [voiceArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [speechSynth setVoice:selectedVoice];
    NSLog(@"new voice %@ ", selectedVoice);
}
```

When the app first loads I get the following output:

> 2012-05-27 15:02:29.040 Speakline[42836:f03] Getting number of rows in
>   table view: 24 
>  2012-05-27 15:02:29.042 Speakline[42836:f03] row
>   selected 2 
>  2012-05-27 15:02:29.043 Speakline[42836:f03] new voice
>   com.apple.speech.synthesis.voice.Alex  2012-05-27 15:02:29.162
>   Speakline[42836:f03] Voice Name Agnes 
> 2012-05-27 15:02:29.163
>   Speakline[42836:f03] Voice Name Albert

I want to make sure I understand fully what is going on here. In order to do this I have a couple of questions.

1. It looks like the `numberOfRowsInTableView:` method was automatically called after the `init` method. Is this correct?
2. How often does `objectValueForTableColumn:` get called? What events prompt that method to get called? Also, in the code there, the `return` statement confused me. Where exactly does this return value go?
3. As a side note they wanted me to connect the Outlets and the AppController via control+clicking (via the connections panel) and linking them in that way. What alternatives are there avaialble for connecting delegates and datasources to different kinds of views without doing this? I am assuming that adding `NSTableViewDelegate` in the controller header file might be one way. If you have the option of control+click connecting all your views to outlets and so on vs programmatically setting it all up is it just a matter of preference at this point? It just seems to me that in order to understand what is going on it might be better to just write the code yourself.

Comment: “It looks like …`numberOfRowsInTableView:`… was automatically called after …`init`…. Is this correct?” That's the only time it can be called. The only way it could be called *during* your `init` method is if your `init` loaded the nib, or otherwise created the table view, set its data source, and put it into a view hierarchy. Then the table view *might* ask things of its data source at some point in that process, before `init` returns. As written, the nib is loaded elsewhere, so your `init` must have already returned before everything between the table view and you, its data source can happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Both numberOfRowsInTableView and objectValueForTableColumn:Row: get called soon after the nib is unarchived (I'm not sure of the exact order of things), so the table view can be populated with data.

2) The loading of the table and reloading or adding new data as well as scrolling will cause objectValueForTableColumn:row: to be called (by the table view). It gets called for each row that is populated.  The value goes to the table view, that's how it gets its data.

3) The other way to connect delegates is to do it in code with setDelegate:, but putting NSTableViewDelegate in the .h file does not do that -- that's just a promise to the compiler that you will implement some or all of the delegate messages.

Comment: Ok i understand now..i think. Just to confirm that if numberOfRowsInTableView returns 24 in my case then the objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row will be called 24 times, sending in the table column(you set the number of columns up in the attributes inspector) and the row(corresponding to the number of rows)

Comment: @cspam: It need not be called exactly 24 times, nor more, nor even necessarily fewer. It will be called as many times as there are rows on the screen, so the table view can display the values you return; the table view may call it for additional rows and/or wait until the user scrolls other rows into view. It also may or may not forget previously-returned values (space vs. time trade-off). Don't worry too much about how many times the table view will call it; your initial optimization should be to follow the advice in the documentation, which is to make that method as efficient as possible.

Comment: ok thanks for the comments and help with the questions. *accepted*